# Are idempotent matrices always a projection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that a projection matrix is always an idempotent matrix, but is it true that a idempotent matrix is always a projection matrix?

Comment: So what's a projection matrix if it's not just an idempotent matrix?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm asking if the converse is true

Comment: @Goldname The point is that you need to provide the definitions you're working with for each of these terms.

Comment: @user296602 Really? I thought these terms were a standard. idempotent matrix just being A*A = A and you know projection matrix I assume

Comment: @Goldname I think what you're learning here is that most mathematicians think of them as synonyms, because it's such a basic theorem that they are the same.

Comment: @Goldname What exactly is your definition of a projection matrix, though? Because I'll bet that if you actually carefully write down the definition, you'll have answered your own question....

Comment: @DustanLevenstein What do you mean? You just said they weren't the same

Comment: @user296602 Wait, I didn't know there were other projection matrices. I meant an orthogonal projection matrix of the form S11 = u1^2, S12 = u1*u2, etc.

Comment: Where "u1^2" is what, and "u1*u2" is what? I think that a lot of the issue here is that you haven't written down *what a projection matrix is* in a careful and rigorous fashion.

Comment: @Goldname I said it's a projection matrix, but not necessarily an orthogonal projection matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $M \in Mat_{n \times n}(F)$ is an idempotent matrix, then you can show that $F^n = \operatorname{Im}(M) \oplus \ker(M)$, and $M$ is the projection onto its image along the kernel.

Note that this is not an *orthogonal* projection in general.

Comment: Ok, what I meant was an orthogonal projection matrix.

Comment: @Goldname then the answer to your question is no. :) Consider, for example, $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, an idempotent matrix which is not an orthogonal projection, because the image and kernel are not perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Won't your answer remain correct even if you omit the words "is an idempotent matrix" from it?

Comment: @EvanAad Not at all. For instance, if $M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, then actually $\operatorname{Im}(M) = \operatorname{ker}(M)$ is a strict subspace of $F^2$.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the terms are synonyms (when applied to matrices.)